# Querying insight-api to dump all addresses with a positive balance

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, leveldb

It's been some time I've been using 'insight-api' (https://github.com/bitpay/insight-api) and I couldn't find any documentation / anything helpful to query leveldb in a way that all addresses with a positive balance get dumped to a file.

I tried blockparser (https://github.com/znort987/blockparser) and while it promises to get balance of all addresses, it is relatively very slow. I just need a proper reference/ documentation/ example to get started.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All Bitcoin Public Keys with non-zero balance](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37291/all-bitcoin-public-keys-with-non-zero-balance)